# Multiple dynamic ui date time fields with date picker in angular model

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax

We are trying to have multiple date fields (g:ui date) , where the id and name of the field would be dynamic.Input field is working with dynamic id an name, the same is not working for g:ui date tag.

input field:

```
<input id="docType_{{id}}" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 docTypeS2" name="{{id}}" />
```

date field

```
<g:ui_date_time id="u_effective_date_{{id}}" name="u_effective_date_{{id}}" value="${jvar_u_effective_date}"/>
```

On click of calendar icon throws an event error (please find attached files).

HTMl Page:

[image: HTML Page Output]

OnClick Event:

[image: id_not_replaced]

OnClick Event Error:

[image: Event_Error]

Comment: Is that datepicker works with angularjs? Why not use a [native solution](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepickerPopup)? Please [edit] the post and show us your JS too

Comment: Date picker doesn't work, when i click on calendar  icon in get the error.

Comment: But if you're trying to select a date using a datepicker then you can use the native directive I posted in my first comment. Is it a date picker or is it also a time picker?

Comment: Its both date and time picker.